# How to create a custom Plugin for Cordova2.3 - Android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a custom plugin for Cordova - android. The purpose of the plugin is to raise an intent for a native android activity on click of a button on an HTML5 screen.
So initially, I would be on an HTML5 screen with a button. On click of button, I should be redirected to a native android activity screen.

Here is a bit of code I have already done,

customplugin.js

```
function CustomPlugin(){};

CustomPlugin.prototype.launchActivity = function(startClass) 
{
alert("@@@ Starting plugin to launch native activity.");
cordova.exec(null, null, 'CustomPlugin', 'launchActivity', [startClass]);
};

if(!window.plugins) {
window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.customplugin) {
   window.plugins.customplugin = new CustomPlugin();
}
```

In this code, however, I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method "launchActivity" of undefined.'
Pls help me with some sample code examples. Thanks in advance.

CustomPlugin.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin 
{
@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException 
    {
        if ("launchActivity".equals(action)) 
        { 
              String goClass = null; if(args.length() > 0) goClass = args.getString(0);

              Log.i("NATIVE", "Launch class : " + goClass); 
              return true;
          } 
          else 
          { 
              return false;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippet, I don't see where you actually execute `launchActivity()`. Better add it to the question, because it seems there is the problem.

First of all, make sure you have the **cordova.js** loaded in your page. Then you use `cordova.exec` (this is an example using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), but that's not necessary, you can use `cordova.exec()` too)

```
define(['cordova'], function (cordova) {
    'use strict';

    var exec = cordova.require('cordova/exec');

    return {
        changeBackground : function (color) {
            exec(function () {}, function () {}, 'Navbar', 'changeBackground', [color]);
        }
    };

});
```

Make sure you add the plugin in **res/xml/plugins.xml**:

```
<plugin name="Navbar" value="my.package.NavbarPlugin"/>
```

To create a plugin, you just extend `org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin`.

```
public class NavbarPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("changeBackground".equals(action)) { ... }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

The problem why it doesn't work is because you are executing `window.customplugin.launchActivity(...)`. `window.customplugin` does not exist, hence you get that you cannot call `launchActivity` of `undefined`.

You need to call `window.plugins.customplugin.launchActivity(...)`

Comment: Hey, I made the changes as you suggested, but its still not working. I am still getting 'Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method "launchActivity" of undefined.'</br> BTW, in the code snippet that I gave with my question, I am not getting the alert "@@@ Starting plugin to launch native activity." at any point of time. Does this mean control is never coming to that part of the code??

Comment: Could you add the code you to execute launchActivity() to your question? The problem lies there.

Comment: <body>
        <div class="app">
            
            <div class="goAndroid" onclick="go()">Go Native</div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customplugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            function go(){
            
          alert('Going Android Native');
          window.customplugin.launchActivity("NativeActivity");
         };
        </script>
    </body>

Comment: About the formatting: you should edit the question. That's easier. But i have found your problem. See my edit: you are accessing the wrong object.

Comment: Wow.. i am atleast getting the alert now. But the control is still not going to my plugin's java code. See my edit for the java code.

Comment: Hey, I got it. I added my plugin    <plugin
            name="CustomPlugin"
            value="org.apache.cordova.example.CustomPlugin" /> in config.xml

Comment: Thanks a million...!!! I had been trying to figure this out for the past 4 days ... !!!

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below code snippet to create a native Cordova plugin for android and configuration needed for call and get response from web side.

**Example :** The current location latitude and longitude from an android device using Cordova native plugin.

**Android Code:**

```
 package com.sample.activity;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;

public class LocationTrackPlugin extends CordovaPlugin implements LocationListener {
public static final String ACTION_START = "GetLocation";
public static CallbackContext callbackContext;
public static Activity activity;

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray jArray,
                       final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
    boolean result = false;
    if (ACTION_START.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        LocationTrackPlugin.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity
                .getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(
                    PluginResult.Status.OK, "false");
            pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
            try {
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            result = true;
            Location location = getCurrentDeviceLocation(activity);
            String my_location = location.getLatitude() + ":" + location.getLongitude();
            PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(
                    PluginResult.Status.OK, my_location);
            pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
            try {
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    return result;

}


public Location getCurrentDeviceLocation(Context contxt) {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    Location location = null;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) contxt
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
        location = getCurrentLocation(provider, locationManager);
        if (location != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            return location;

        } else {
            location = getCurrentLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    locationManager);
            if (location != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                return location;
            } else {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        }
    } else
        Log.d("Location", "No Provider Found");
    return location;
}

public Location getCurrentLocation(String provider,
                                   LocationManager locationManager) {
    Location newlocation = null;
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            newlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return newlocation;
        }
    }
    return newlocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**Manifestfile.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Config.xml** (File is located at appname/cordova/Config.xml)

```
 <feature name="LocationTrackPlugin">
    <param name="android-package"   value=com.sample.activity.LocationTrackPlugin" />
</feature>
```

**ShowLocation.js**

```
  callGetlocationPlugin: function() {
    if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
        cordova.exec(
                function(result) {
                    console.log("Native call success", result);
                                      },
                function() {
                    console.log('Native call failed');
                },
                'LocationTrackPlugin', 'GetLocation', null);
    }
}
```